# Receiving an empty body in a retrofit response

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am using retrofit to get data from the ticketmaster API
My class Event:
`public class Event implements Parcelable {
private String name;
private String id;
private String url;
private String startDate;
private String time;
private String notes;
private String image;
private Boolean ageRestrictions;
private EventPlace place;

```
public Event() {}

public Event(String name, String id, String url, String image, String startDate,
             String time, String notes, boolean ageRestrictions, EventPlace place) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.url = url;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.time = time;
    this.notes = notes;
    this.image = image;
    this.ageRestrictions = ageRestrictions;
    this.place = place;
}

protected Event(Parcel in) {
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.id = in.readString();
    this.url = in.readString();
    this.startDate = in.readString();
    this.time = in.readString();
    this.notes = in.readString();
    this.image = in.readString();
    this.ageRestrictions = in.readByte() != 0;
    this.place = in.readParcelable(EventPlace.class.getClassLoader());
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getNotes() {
    return notes;
}

public void setNotes(String notes) {
    this.notes = notes;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public Boolean getAgeRestrictions() {
    return ageRestrictions;
}

public void setAgeRestrictions(Boolean ageRestrictions) {
    this.ageRestrictions = ageRestrictions;
}


public static final Parcelable.Creator<Event> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Event>() {
    @Override
    public Event createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Event(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Event[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Event[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(@NonNull Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.url);
    dest.writeString(this.startDate);
    dest.writeString(this.time);
    dest.writeString(this.notes);
    dest.writeString(this.image);
    dest.writeByte(this.ageRestrictions ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
    dest.writeParcelable(this.place, flags);
}
```

}
    `The main method is:`     public void fetchEvents(String type, String city, String startDateTime, String time, long lastUpdate) {

```
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // It gets the news from the Web Service if the last download
    // of the news has been performed more than FRESH_TIMEOUT value ago
    //TODO sistemare la condizione per l'aggiornamento
    //if (currentTime - lastUpdate > FRESH_TIMEOUT) {
    if (true) {
        Call<EventApiResponse> eventsResponseCall = eventsApiService.getEvents(type, city, startDateTime, time,
                                                                                "ymPPalpoNoG8lG5xyca0AQ6uhACG4y3j");

        eventsResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<EventApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<EventApiResponse> call,
                                   @NonNull Response<EventApiResponse> response) {

                if(response.body() != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<Event> eventsList = response.body().getEvents();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response code: " + response.code());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response body: " + response.body());
                    responseCallback.onSuccess(eventsList, System.currentTimeMillis());
                    //TODO saveDataInDatabase(eventsList);
                } else {
                    responseCallback.onFailure(application.getString(R.string.error_retrieving_events));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<EventApiResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

                if(t.getMessage() != null)
                    Log.d(TAG, t.getMessage());
                else
                    Log.d(TAG, "messaggio di errore nullo");

                responseCallback.onFailure(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } else {
        //TODO`
```

and the call method is:
`    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
recyclerViewEvents = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

```
    recyclerViewEvents.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewEvents.setAdapter(recyclerViewEventsAdapter);

    eventsRepository.fetchEvents("music", "324", "2024-06-01T08:00:00Z", "2024-06-30T08:00:00Z", 10);
}`
```

When I try to parse from a json local file it works, but when i try with retrofit i get a OK response code(400) but an empty body.